# Can google maps have a transparent bg?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Can google maps have a transparent bg? I've been messing with the paramaters but can't find a solution. I'm using the JS API.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting the opacity on the container to which the map is applied? If I recall, you pass an element as the map container, which the Google JS library then renders the map to.

Answer (score 12):

There is a way to give the map a transparent background with Google Maps API V3. The [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapOptions) object has a property called `backgroundColor`, which sets the background colour of the map. If you use an HSLA color value, you can control the opacity of this background colour to create the transparency.

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 1,
styles: mapStyles,
backgroundColor: 'hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0)',
};
```

In addition to setting this color, you also need to use some map styles to hide the water (or whatever you want to be transparent).

Here is a codepen demonstrating the effect: 
http://codepen.io/verticalgrain/pen/LVRezx

Comment: Note: as of 2022, this pen "sort of" works. It will render the water transparent, however: the water actually covers the landmass to create the defined land masses. You'll get some pretty weird looking results if, like me, you were looking to have just land masses and have the water areas show through to the site behind.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be possible by setting the `opacity` with CSS to a value less than 1. All modern browsers support `opacity` either natively or with a proprietary directive.

```
<!-- The container to which the map is rendered by the Google JS library -->
<div id="mapContainer" style="opacity:0.5"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't this just make everything 50% opaque? I'm looking to make the bg and elements like water 100% translucent.

Comment: @fancy - I don't know about that. I couldn't find anything on the web and I've never done it. That would require Google to support a fairly sophisticated alpha channel rendering system and return the maps in a format which supports a 32-bit alpha channel (like PNG).

Comment: Right, I might try using static maps and using canvas to remove the parts I don't want. Only problem is I would need to cache the image on my server and I think that ids agains the google TOS. :(