# ggmap layering on a second transparent background google map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to unsuccessfully to layer on a second google map of just roads using inset_ggmap

```
m <- ggmap(dt_map_b) +
  geom_polygon(data = map_data, 
               aes(fill = outcomes,
                   x = long, 
                   y = lat.x, 
                   group = group),
               alpha = 0.5) +
  inset_ggmap(dt_map_r)
```

Everything works fine but when I turned off the visibility of the terrain features I discovered that it is all back underneath smothering my initial image

[image: black background like spilled ink]

I know it is possible to change the background color of the maps [with the google api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724043/can-google-maps-have-a-transparent-bg/30384853) but is it possible to change the background color from ggmap? Maybe by changing what gets added to the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  m <- leaflet(outcomes_map) %>%

  addMapPane("base_map", zIndex = 410) %>%    # Level 1: base
  addMapPane("polygons", zIndex = 420) %>%    # Level 2: polygons
  addMapPane("waters", zIndex = 430) %>%      # Level 3: waters
  addMapPane("roads", zIndex = 440) %>%       # Level 4: roads
  addMapPane("labels", zIndex = 450) %>%      # Level 5: labels

    # adds in the base map

    addTiles(urlTemplate = base_map,
             options = pathOptions(pane = "base_map")) %>%

    # adds in the polygons containing the loaded data

    addPolygons(color = ~pal5(rank),
                weight = 1,
                fillOpacity  = 1,
                options = pathOptions(pane = "polygons")) %>%

    # adds in the other layers for aesthetics like roads, water, and place labels

    addTiles(urlTemplate = water_map,
             options = pathOptions(pane = "waters")) %>%

    addTiles(urlTemplate = road_map,
             options = pathOptions(pane = "roads",
                                   opacity = 0.75)) %>%

    addTiles(urlTemplate = label_map,
             options = pathOptions(pane = "labels")) %>%

      setView(lng = -80.843297, lat = 35.225256, zoom = 11)

        # you can export as either an interactive map or a static image

        mapshot(m, url = file.path(graph_export_path,"alrighty.html"))

        mapshot(m, file = file.path(graph_export_path,"alrighty.png"))
```

Turns out this is much easier to accomplish just using leaflet and mapshot(). All you really have to do is make a couple different layers for the features you are interested in and then create panes to organize them in your desired order. You'll need to set up a mapbox account and pull in the maps using the api but that's pretty straightforward in the leaflet for R documentation. And this way you have much more customization of how your maps look!